# how to create loading screen while switching between screens in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, loading

On my app, I'm pulling up a list of recipes for the user to choose from. The screen downloads about 10 images to display, which causes the app to take some time to load before displaying everything. The screen freezes mid-switch for about 5 seconds, then displays the recipes. I need to know if there's some way to put up a "loading" screen so the switch isn't visible. I've googled it and didnt get satisfactory results, as most results pertained to the loading screen when the app first opens. Any ideas for me?

**EDIT**

To add more detail, I've already tried adding a view controller on top of the first one and removing it after the screen finished loading. That still froze until the one below loaded. I'm not really sure where to start with this, so any suggestions for further reading or anything would be helpful

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far and details about what kind of screen you want to display. Stackoverflow is more of a help community and not necessarily for others to be doing a complete solution for you.

Comment: free the main thread by offloading stuff. see AJ B's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would download the images asynchronously and display a UIActivityIndicatorView. This will show the user that the app is not frozen because the indicator will be spinning, and your main thread won't be locked since you are downloading the images asynchronously.

Also try doing some earnest research before asking a question, chances are someone else had the same problem. Check out this answer, it is similar to what you are trying to do.

[How to UIActivityIndicatorView during perform segue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666115/how-to-uiactivityindicatorview-during-perform-segue)

edit:

In order to segue the view when all images have downloaded:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                     ^{
                         //download your images
                     });

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                      ^{
                          //images have downloaded, end uiactivityindicator, segue to the next view

                      });
```

Comment: well asynchronous is definitely the way to go, but i still cant load the page until the images are downloaded. it wont be complete

Comment: You can use a dispatch_group to find out when your async task to download the images has completed. Example in answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Put activity indicator on your view controller with recipes:

```
self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(40.0, 20.0, 100.0, 100.0);
self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
```

Then when it should start, start it and add this to main view:

```
self.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
```

once data is loaded, stop and remove activity indicator:

```
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[self.activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
```